# Python Selenium Browser Element Not Found Error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to develop a python bot but when I run the following code down below it opens the first link from the list correctly but then crashes. I'm getting an element not found error not sure how to fix this. Im new at python.

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
chromedriver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk/usr/usernamehere")
links = chromedriver.find_elements("xpath", "//ol[@class='pagination__items']//a[@href]")

# Create a list to store the opened window handles
window_handles = []

for link in links:
    url = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(url)
    
    # Open the link in a new tab
    chromedriver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"', '_blank');")
    
    # Switch to the newly opened tab
    chromedriver.switch_to.window(chromedriver.window_handles[-1])
    
      # Wait for an element on the page to become visible
    element = WebDriverWait(chromedriver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//some_xpath_selector"))
    )
    # Perform your actions on the page here
    # For example, you can get the page title:
    print(chromedriver.title)
    
    # Add the window handle to the list
    window_handles.append(chromedriver.current_window_handle)
    
# Switch back to the first tab
chromedriver.switch_to.window(chromedriver.window_handles[0])

# Close all the other tabs
for handle in window_handles[1:]:
    chromedriver.switch_to.window(handle)
    chromedriver.close()
    
# Switch back to the first tab and quit the browser
chromedriver.switch_to.window(chromedriver.window_handles[0])
chromedriver.quit()
```

The error Im getting when I run this code is;

```
    [20612:16724:0323/231628.565:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [23:16:28.565] USB: usb_service_win.cc:104 SetupDiGetDeviceProperty({{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}, 6}) failed: Element not found. (0x490)

[20612:16724:0323/231628.566:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [23:16:28.565] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

[20612:16724:0323/231628.566:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [23:16:28.566] USB: usb_service_win.cc:104 SetupDiGetDeviceProperty({{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}, 6}) failed: Element not found. (0x490)

[20612:16724:0323/231628.580:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [23:16:28.580] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

[20612:16724:0323/231628.599:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(222)] [23:16:28.598] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Comment: _Element not found_: Which element not found? Update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0):

`ElementNotFoundException`s are thrown when you try to find a specific element, and it does not exist when the driver looks for it using your location strategy. This normally means one of two things.

One, the xpath you're using to find the element doesn't work.

Two, if the xpath works, then the element isn't loaded in under that xpath when the driver tries to find it. Expected conditions can be a bit finnicky, so I recommend using the `WebDriverWait.Until()` method, and do something similar to `WebDriverWait.Until(d => driver.FindElements(xpath).Count > 0);`. This will continue once the element exists on the website.